# PHP Mass String Replace

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, str-replace

In PHP, I want to execute `str_replace` on multiple variables, efficiently, when all variables shall abide by the same `str_replace` values.

Bascially, I am expecting to see the following:

```
$var1=str_replace("0.00","\$0",$var1);
$var2=str_replace("0.00","\$0",$var2);
$var3=str_replace("0.00","\$0",$var3);
$var4=str_replace("0.00","\$0",$var4);
...
```

this is repetitive and especially annoying when adding more variables to such replace. I have constructed the following loop

```
foreach ( array("var1","var2","var3","var4") as $variablename ) {
${$variablename} = str_replace("0.00","\$0",${$variablename});
}
```

This loop works (for those of you viewing this page looking for such an example) , however, I am not convinced that this is the most efficient way (assuming mass replacing)

Any thoughts?

Comment: There would be a more efficient way if your list of numbered variables were an array instead.

Comment: ...Agree with @mario.  If the variables are related as they appear to be by virtue of requiring the same set of operations, then they may belong in a data structure.

Comment: so `str_replace("0.00","\$0",array("var1","var2",...))` as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter of `str_replace` can accept an array of variables to perform the replace on. It should be better performing that any custom loop.

```
$results = str_replace("0.00","\$0", array($var1, $var2, $var3));
```

Comment: I was aware that both the first and second paramaters of this command accepted arrays, but I didn't remember reading about an array-applicable third parameter in the manual. I appreciate your answer. It looks cleaner than mine, and it makes sense too :)

Comment: As a note to others. This works, indeed. The `$results` variable is stored as an array, and in no way does the variable itself interfere with normal operations. When printing the array, `print_r($results)` it displays the values of `$var1`,`$var2`, and `$var3`, however the "keys" are numerical, and do not contain the original variable name.

Comment: @timtj: If you want to retain the variable names, then an uncommon workaround is creating the array via `compact("var1", "var2", "var3")`. You might even use `extract(str_replace("from", "to", compact("var1", "var2")));` to keep/overwrite your original varlist.

Comment: It seems like a possible workaround. However, is it efficient or will it bog down after multiple variables?